# Issue with using Sampler2D with a Shader

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl, fbo

**! I am aware that there are easier ways to draw to the screen than this, but i need to do it this specific way !**

I am drawing to a texture through a fbo.
I am then using a shader to re-draw it onto the screen, doing so with a sampler2D (of the texture) and having the shader set gl_fragColor to the color of the sampler2D at the specific point the fragment shader is at.

The issue i am having is that the display buffer (which the shader is drawing the fbo to) is only a solid blue, even though i draw a white squares to the fbo with a blue background.

My Code:

Main Render Loop:

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        //Drawing on the fbo a blue background and white square
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboID);
        glColor3f(0,0,1);
        drawQuad(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        drawQuad(0,0,50,50);

        //Trying to draw the texture from the previous fbo
        //on to the display buffer with a fragment shader,
        //however it only draws a blue background, no white square.

        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texID);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex"), 0);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "width"), WIDTH);
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "height"), HEIGHT);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS); {
            glVertex2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, HEIGHT);
            glVertex2f(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            glVertex2f(WIDTH, 0);
        } glEnd();
        glUseProgram(0);

        Display.update();
    }
```

My Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float width;
uniform float height;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D( tex, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(width, height));
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Init method for the fbo:

```
    texID=glGenTextures();
    fboID=glGenFramebuffersEXT();

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

I think one reason why this is happening could be becuase i am not correctly passing the Sampler2D to the shader but i not sure how to fix it.

If any could tell why this is happening or how to fix it (or even just a point in the right direction) it would be much appreciated!

(Sorry for any bad English!)

Comment: Fixed pipelilne, i.e., functions like `glBegin)/glEnd()` doesnt mixes with programmatically pipeline (shaders). You cant use both at same time

Comment: @Amadeus: Yes you can, you just cannot use those functions in a core profile. It really has nothing to do with fixed-function operation; immediate mode was deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and removed in 3.1. Of course the fixed-function pipeline was also deprecated and removed at the same time, so you might easily equate the two things as the same.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes you can, but it can or can not render to screen, which gives you bugs that are difficult to find

Comment: That would be true if `glBegin (...)`, `glEnd (...)` and friends were part of the fixed-function pipeline, but they are not. They exist outside of the render pipeline altogether, they package vertex state together and define primitive topology before the first stage (vertex processing) even starts. An example of something that was part of the fixed-function pipeline would be vertex lighting, that used to be applied during vertex transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You have transposed your calls to `glUniform1i (...)` and `glUseProgram (...)`.

At the time that `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "tex"), 0);` is executed, the currently active program is **0** and that should in fact be generating the following error:

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if there is no current program object.

If you swap the two lines mentioned above, that should fix your problem. In the future you should make a point of checking `glGetError (...)` when something does not work.

---

***UPDATE***: Now that the original problem is fixed, you are not setting the texture minification filter correctly.

To set enumerants, you must use `glTexParameteri (...)`. `glTexParameterf (...)` is going to interpret the value passed as a floating-point number and `GL_LINEAR` (**0x2601**) has type `GLenum` (32-bit unsigned integer). Fortunately all core OpenGL enums only use the lower 16-bits so they can be expressed precisely as 32-bit floats (can express all integers up to 2<sup>24</sup>), but you can see why you would not want to convert an integer constant to a float.

#### Therefore, the following line:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

#### Needs to be:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

---

***UPDATE 2***: You must use normalized texture coordinates when using `texture2D (...)`.

`gl_FragCoord.xy` has the range [**0**, `width`] and [**0**, `height`], which is outside the normalized range for any framebuffer larger than **1x1**. To fix that, you must divide by width and height.

`texelFetch (...)` allows you to use unnormalized coordinates, but it requires GLSL 1.30 and you would have to cast `gl_FragCoord.xy` to `ivec2` to use it. It may also prove inconvenient if you ever draw into an FBO that has different dimensions than your window.

Comment: @Meta: Can you add the code where you allocate and attach the texture to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` of your FBO?

Comment: I added the init method for the fbo, is that what you mean?

Comment: I changed the line but it still doesn't work :(  ill update q with your update

Comment: would it be helpful if  i uploaded the whole class?

Comment: @Meta: No, this should be adequate. I do not see anything else wrong with the code. Is `glGetError (...)` returning something other than `GL_NO_ERROR`?

Comment: No, it is returning 0 (no error i think) when i print it. I have tried placing it in multiple places. Also I still have my supisions about when i pass the sampler2D to the shader, could something be wrong with this?

Comment: @Meta: No, not if you are getting a blue color back. That suggests that if anything is wrong it is the texture coordinates.

Comment: Ok, i also noticed that when i drew an extra WHITE QUAD (500 by 500) at 0,0 it only displayed white not blue this time.

Comment: @Meta: Can you try `texture2D( tex, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2 (width, height))`, where width and height are whatever you used for your FBO? Ideally you would not use the window-space fragment coordinate for your texture coordinate because that has the range [0,{width|height}] and will cause texture coordinate wrapping to kick in. You either want normalized texture coordinates (range [0,1]) or cast `gl_FragCoord.xy` to `ivec2` and use `texelFetch (...)`.

Comment: i have tried adding it but get a error saying the shader didn't compile, i assume thats my bad coding. I will update the shader.

Comment: spelling is very bad sorry

Comment: It now displays the white square, thank you so much!

Comment: @Meta: By the way, you really should not edit your question like that in the future. The original code that my answer refers to is completely gone. If you make changes to the question, you should leave the original code in place and mention the lines of code you changed.

Comment: I am very new to stack overflow so that is very helpful :)